# Reference request: Applications of representation theory of finite groups

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory, book-recommendation, applications

I'd like to know if there's a book with a lot of examples (from physics, chemistry, etc..) of applications of representation theory of finite groups.

I think it must exist, but I couldn't find anything of the sort...
Thank you in advance

Comment: John S. Lomont's [Applications of Finite Groups](https://books.google.com/books?id=68HiBQAAQBAJ) may have what you're looking for. There's a pretty extensive chapter detailing applications in physics.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that

Comment: I've added the (book-recommendation) and (applications) tags, but in doing so removed the general (group-theory) tag. If you think it should be in there after all, please replace one of the tags. Unfortunately, there is a maximum of five tags per post.